Jenkins: clone 2 repo and one access to another
I have 2 repositories "PS" and "QA", in the "PS" project I run some integration tests that requires some files as input from the "QA" project so I access them using direct path ../../qa/path/to/files/my-file.txt.
Locally this works fine and the integration tests complete successfully because I have both repositories cloned side by side.
Now I want to run these tests on Jenkins so in the build configuration I've told Jenkins to clone both repos in its workspace, but I get
No Such File "my-file.txt" exception in the build

Not sure if the QA has been cloned as well or not! 
This is the configuration

isn't this configuration enough to make Jenkins clone these repos so tests from PS can access files inside QA folder?

If you don't clean the workspace, after the build runs, go into your Jenkins host machine and check to see if the file exists there & that the repo has been cloned
